# How to add command parameter to windows shortcut

Tags: windows, command, lnk

When I typed this command in `cmd.exe`:
`E:\mywamp\redis-2.8.19\redis-server.exe --maxheap 512mb`

it ran successfully.

I want to create a windows shortcut to start `redis` quickly. So I created a shortcut in windows and filled the target input with the content above. But when I double click the shortcut, it just disappears. It seemed the parameter of `--maxheap 512mb` is not passed to the program of `redis-server.exe`.
[image: the configuration of my shotcut]
I have tried to use quotation marks to enclose the target string, but the problem is still here.

Comment: That should work. I have several shortcuts like that where i have the input flags in the target field. Could you try with only one "dash"?

Comment: Might be an oddity with this particular executable.  The quick workaround is to create a batch file, and point the shortcut at the batch file.

Comment: Thansk to @HarryJohnston , I think the  solution you have given is good and resolving my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should only encapsulate the path to the file in quotation:

"E:\mywamp\redis-2.8.19\redis-server.exe" --maxheap 512mb